# Delete dynamically created buttons using a normal button

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I've been trying to make a button that removes the latest dynamically created button on my form app (Visual studio). The code is in c#.  This is the code I've tried:

```
private void deletebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Button btn = (Button)sender;
     Controls.Remove(btn);
}
```

Instead of deleting the dynamic button it deletes the button that is supposed to delete the dynamic button. Here is the code that creates the dynamic button:

```
private void button1_Click_7(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
     int hash = i % 4;
     i++;
     Button btn = new Button();
     btn.Text = Buttonnametext.Text;
     btn.Size = new Size(118, 52);
     btn.Location = new Point(120 * hash, 55 * Y);
     Buttonnametext.Text = "Example";
     Buttonnametext.ForeColor = Color.Silver;
     Controls.Add(btn);
     btn.Click += (ssender, a) =>
     {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(websitetextbox.Text);        
     };

     if (i % 4 == 0)
     {
         Y++;
     }
}
```

Comment: All buttons are generated dynamically in the `InitializeComponents` method. There are no "normal" buttons, all of them are the same. Your original code deletes the *sender* button. If you want to delete a different button you have to store it somewhere - a field, a property or Queue<Button>. `button1` is nothing more than a field holding a reference to a generated button

Comment: If you only want to delete *one* button, store it in a field before the call to `Controls.Add(btn)`, eg `_latestButton=btn;`. If you want to be able to delete multiple buttons from last to first, create a `Stack<Button>` field and push the buttons to it. When you want to delete one, `Pop` it and delete it

Comment: All answers here *follow suit*, in a way, and call `Controls.Remove(button)`. Whatever answer you choose, I suggest not to use this method. Use `[Button].Dispose()` Instead. This will dispose of the object you create and it will also remove the control from the `Controls` collection.

Comment: Disposing of the controls is not optional. It's really important to dispose them. If you just remove, the control is still alive and unmanaged resources will be still in use which may result in a handle leak if you don't dispose them.

Answer (score 1):

All buttons are generated dynamically in the `InitializeComponents` method. There are no "normal" buttons, all of them are the same.

Your original code deletes the sender button. If you want to delete a different button you have to store it somewhere - a field, a property or Stack. `button1` itself is nothing more than a field holding a reference to a button created inside `InitializeComponents`

If you only want to delete one button, store it in a field before the call to Controls.Add(btn), eg:

```
Button _lastButton;
private void button1_Click_7(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
     ...
     _lastButton=btn;
     Controls.Add(btn);
     ...
}

private void deletebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(_lastButton!=null)
     {
         Controls.Remove(_lastButton);
     }
}
```

If you want to be able to delete multiple buttons from last to first, create a Stack field and push the buttons to it. When you want to delete one, Pop it and delete it

```
Stack<Button> _buttons=new Stack<Button>;
private void button1_Click_7(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
     ...
     _buttons.Push(btn);
     Controls.Add(btn);
     ...
}

private void deletebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(_buttons.TryPop(out var btn)
     {
         Controls.Remove(btn);
     }
}
```

**Update**

The code above is just for demonstration purposes. Removing the button from the `Controls` collection isn't enough. The *event handlers* have to be removed too, and finally, the button must be disposed. Otherwise the code will leak delegates and GDI handles.

Instead of using a lambda, `Click`'s event handler must become a separate method, eg :

```
void SpawnOnClick(object sender, EventArgs args) 
{
    Process.Start(websitetextbox.Text);        
};

private void button1_Click_7(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
     ...
     Controls.Add(btn);
     btn.Click+=SpawnOnClick;
     _buttons.Push(btn);
     ...
}

private void deletebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(_buttons.TryPop(out var btn)
     {
         Controls.Remove(btn);
         btn.Click-=SpawnOnClick;
         btn.Dispose();
     }
}
```

Comment: Nice, using a `Stack` is way cleaner than a `List`

Comment: Disposing of the controls is not optional. It's really important to dispose them.

Comment: @RezaAghaei didn't say it is. Removing the event handlers it even more important. Without knowing what the actual code does though it's hard to create a method that correctly removes the handlers and disposes the control

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler is getting the sender (i.e. the button that fired the event) and then deleting that. A different approach, that would work, would be to store the button in a private field rather than a local variable when you create it. So rather than:

```
Button btn = new Button();
```

You would have:

```
_btn = new Button();
```

where `_btn` is your private Button.

Then your event handler would look like:

```
private void deletebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // some error checking that _btn exists etc
    Controls.Remove(_btn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form class, you can add a field that stores the buttons you've added dynamically :

```
List<Button> MyButtons = new List<Button>();
```

Then, in the method that adds the buttons dynamically, you can save a reference to that button in the previously created property :

```
private void button1_Click_7(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your code

    MyButtons.Add(btn);
}
```

Now, in the method that deletes the buttons, you can use that list to retrieve the last button :

```
private void deletebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // if you have created at least 1 button
    if (MyButtons.Count() > 0)
    {
        Button ButtonToRemove = MyButtons.Last(); // get the last added button
        Controls.Remove(ButtonToRemove); // remove it from the controls
        MyButtons.Remove(ButtonToRemove); // remove it from the list too
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using control.Controls.Find(string, boolean).
Why? you will search through the parent's (control) descendants for the control name, when it has been found (even if several instances with the same name is found), it will return the result in Control[]

Example below

```
if(control.Controls.Find("target control name", true).Length > 0)
control.Controls.Find("target control name", true)[0].Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using something to distinguish between your dynamic created buttons and the others.
For example storing something in the Tag property.

## Create a new button

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Text ="Test";
btn.Size = new Size(118, 52);
btn.Tag = true; // any value you base on ,to check if is dynamicly created 
btn.ForeColor = Color.Silver;
Controls.Add(btn);
```

## Remove last created button

```
 var lastBtn =Controls[Controls.Count - 1];
 if (lastBtn != null && lastBtn.Tag != null && (bool)lastBtn.Tag)
 {
   Controls.Remove(lastBtn);
 }
```